# pre background color not responding to adjacent image padding

Tags: html, css, padding, background-color, pre

[This page](https://wayneca.neocities.org/Wolfenstein/modding.html#themap) will show the problem. The `pre` tag has a background-color that is still butting against the image, despite the image defining a `padding` on the right of 16 pixels. The text is aligned as it should be, but the `pre` background-color isn't. Is there a way to fix this?

[image: Screenshot of spacing issue]

Comment: Add display: flex; to pre tag.

Comment: The display:flex answer solved it. The margin answer did nothing.

Comment: Re edit - added screenshot in case the link becomes deprecated

Comment: I'll have to stress that in your particular case you should only add the `display: flex` as inline styles to the `pre` causing issues as opposed to writing them in a css as that would open a whole new can of worms (i.e, mess with your other `pre` tags)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use display: table. and foot.